# MariaDB commands out of sync

Tags: mysql, git, raspberry-pi, mariadb, gitea

[image]I try to install a self-hosted Git on my Raspberry Pi 4b but I run into one issue several times. When I try to initialize the git the first time I cant do it because my MariaDB throws this error: Database setting is invalid: commands out of sync. Did you run multiple statements at once?
can someone helps me?

I tried to install GOGs and Gitea but both throw the same Error

Comment: Turn on the "general log" to see what commands are being performed.

Answer (score 2):

I solved changing `127.0.0.1:3306` to `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`